# How to schedule a process?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to run a process once every 24 hours at midnight. It won't matter if it is 12:00:00 or 12:00:03, just as long as it is around midnight.

Would I need a timer control checking what time it is every minute or is there a more sophisticated/simpler way of doing this?

What would be the if statement to check whether it is midnight currently?

Comment: I'm not a VBA guy (and I don't know your environment), but wouldn't this require your database to be open at midnight?

Comment: This article shows a few traps set when using the Access Timer event and "probably" some workarounds http://www.bluemoosetech.com/article.php?jid=8

Comment: Good link, @belisarius. A nice addition to it would be if it mentioned that you can often run a vbScript with Windows Scheduler to do data updates, for instance.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton You're right. But I guess the moral of the story could be something like "if you need a server and a DB, let them be."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a need to leave the database open all the time?

If not, consider creating a task with Windows scheduler to open your database at midnight.  Use an autoexec macro which kicks off your process when the database opens.

If you don't want that process to run every time the database opens, name the macro something other than autoexec.  Then use Access' */exec* command option with your macro name when you create the task in Windows scheduler.

**Update**: In answer to "*what would be the if statement to check whether it is midnight currently*", you can use this expression:

```
If TimeValue(Now()) = #12:00:00 AM# Then
```

However, I doubt that will do you much good because that will only ever be True precisely at midnight.  You want your process to run at 12:01 AM if it hasn't already.  So I think what you need is a CompletedJobs table with a Date/Time field, run_date, and a unique index on that field.  Then you can use DCount with the Date function to see whether today's date exists in CompletedJobs.

```
DCount("run_date", "CompletedJobs", "run_date = #" & Date() & "#")
```

If DCount <> 0, your process has run today.  If DCount = 0, run your process, then insert today's date into CompletedJobs.

```
INSERT INTO CompletedJobs (run_date)
VALUES (Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use task scheduler to run a vbs file which could use ActiveX to run the code you want in your database

Comment: you could open the access file with the code getting executed (assume this code is already written) by a macro named autoexec.

Comment: vbs = vbScript. It's very similar to VBA but with not data typing for variables (all variables are variants). VBA code is usually pretty easy to convert, as long as you understand how to adapt it to use late binding.